# How to remove a li containing a specific child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so say I have:

```
<li>
    <span id="foo">bar</span>
</li>

<li>
    <span id="abc">123</span>
</li>
```

and I want to remove the li with child "span id=foo". How do I do that with Jquery?

I tried something like:

```
$("li:has(span[id=foo])").remove();
```

does not seem to be working... Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's what he *wants* to do.

Comment: Yeah i confused it with some other line problems, now all good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try this:

```
$("li:has(span#foo)").remove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KVMfB/1/)**

But it seems your code is just working fine. **[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/KVMfB/2/)**

Comment: It never occurred to me to *check* his original code; I just assumed it was a quirk of jQuery that made a valid-seeming selector fail. Tsk... +1

Comment: Thanks yes the code did work. I confused the problem with some other line in my project. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

Select the child, not the parent:

```
$('#foo').closest('li').remove();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n2wFa/).

Or:

```
$('li:has(#foo)').remove();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n2wFa/1/).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).

Comment: No problem at all! On the bright side, you've at least narrowed down the possibilities for the actual problem. =)